# Rows getting added to gridview on footer linkbutton click in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I am having a static GridView with pagesize="200". For ex: If I have 300 records then I split and show them in 2 pages where 2nd page will have 100 records. Also I show footer only in last page.

There is a linkbutton in footer and when I click on it for the first time, (100)empty rows are generated in the last page. Means, every page will have 200 as page size and since last page is having only 100 records and remaining 100 rows are added as empty rows to accommodate 200 page size.

When postback happens the footer which I had earlier gets into datarow.

`Note: I'm not facing this issue when I debug in my local and I get this after deploying to application server.`

Comment: What is the code written on that LinkButton?

Comment: @mathewtinuthomas - In RowCommand of gridview I have written the code to navigate to other page.

Comment: can you paste the code here